# Azure web app configuration settings during azure dev ops deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am new to Azure dev ops and trying to deploy a azure web app to test and prod stages. I have developed two stages test and prod.

After the test is tested properly, then i will deploy the same to prod.

My question is .

the test web app points to the "test environment" in the config settings of the test website in the azure portal. And the production site points to the "prod environment" in the config settings in the portal.

so at the time of deployment to test and Prod , where do i specify the config settings for each environment?

I mean is there any provision in the "STAGES" where i can specify the settings for the test  website and Prod website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can define variables in Azure DevOps specific to stages of your release pipeline.

Once you are in edit mode for your release pipeline, click the "Variables" tab. Once you add a new variable, you can select the "Scope". There will be a scope for each individual stage of your release, and a scope which covers all stages ("Release").

You can also do the same in code [using YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch).

Comment: thanks @cameron but i did as you said but not able to see the application setting key in the portal when it was deployed finally. any ideas if anything i have missed?

Comment: @user3276487 I'm probably missing what exactly it is you're asking. As I understood it, your question was the last statement in your post, essentially "Can you set values that will change per stage in an ADO release pipeline?".

There will be additional configuration on top of this to pass this value to the specific release task you're using. For that, I'd need to know which task you're using. Can I assume a simple Azure App Service Deploy?

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV3

Comment: You could also just add a simple Azure CLI task to set the config settings in the portal:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV1/Readme.md

Comment: @cameron -- finally worked. Seems like i had misconfigured by doing a swap in the portal. But now i am using individual uat and prod app services in the deployment.I am marking your as an answer. thanks for the help.